# Navigation application in mac

Tags: cocoa, navigation, macos

i am new to mac development, i have to create an application which will have multiple views/windows like in installation wizard( where few option are selected one after other etc). Can any one provide me a link for any such tutorial or where can i refer them. sample app will be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you actually are making an “installation wizard”, I'd highly recommend you make an Installer package instead. It's less work, more likely to work (installation has thousands of corner cases where a custom-made installer is likely to fail), and if you *really* need custom UI for something (and you probably don't), you can make an Installer plug-in for it and include that in your package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question exactly like this was asked recently [Presenting multiple views sequentially - OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806241/presenting-multiple-views-sequentially-os-x/3806679#3806679) . In short use M3NavigationView from Martin Pilkington http://www.mcubedsw.com/dev

Basically it pushes and pops NSViewControllers on a stack and allows you to animate between them. It's the easiest solution to this I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic implementation would use a tabless NSTabView where each tab contains the specific "screens" (views) in your "wizard" (usually called an "assistant" on Mac OS X). You can select tabs by index or identifier, which map to your own logical order. Alternatively (to make animation easier), you could use plain NSViews (with outlets to each) and use `[[containerView animator] replaceSubview:existingSubview with:targetView]`.

The rest is a matter of designing the path through the view (ie, choosing option B on view 3 skips view 4 and goes straight to 5, etc.). I recommend mapping this out on paper or with your favorite flowchart software, then build the UI to match.