# NSButton Doesn't Respond to Click When Putting inside M3NavigationView

Tags: cocoa, navigation, nsbutton, nsviewcontroller

I'm using [M3NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837556/navigation-application-in-mac) to do view navigations, but there I got a problem when push one view inside(some animation happens here),  A button doesn't responds to mouse click most of the time, I'll have to click it twice,

[image: screen shot]

I **clicked** *once* on the button, and it seems the mouse up event doesn't happen. I have to click the button again to trigger my action.

After more testing today, I found the button inside works normally after it is displayed for 2 seconds. more weird.

Is there anyone knows that going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used one out of two of my apple developer support service, and get it solved. row double clicked of PXListView needs to change a little to work with M3NavigationView

```
if([theEvent clickCount]>1) {
    if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(listView:rowDoubleClicked:)]) {
     [[self delegate] listView:self rowDoubleClicked:[theCell row]];
     return; //return here, this is the change
    }
}
```