# NSView enterFullScreenWithOptions: scaling the NSView

Tags: cocoa, macos

So, in reference to : [Kiosk Applications - OS X programming - Multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800253/kiosk-applications-os-x-programming-multiple-monitors)

I have an 800x600 NSView and I need to scale this proportionally when I enter full screen mode using NSView's `enterFullScreenModeWithOptions`.

Right now, what's happening is the UI elements are stationary at where they were initially defined and the view is occupying the full screen mode. To top this off, my view has a background image which occupies the top left 800x600 square on the monitor too. So how do I scale everything in the view proportionally to fit the screen when in full screen mode?

Thanks again, 
Teja

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a viewer, which inherits form NSView. Before my image gets drawn, I do the resize `[image setSize:size]` to fit my image to the fullscreen.

```
if([myviewer isInFullScreenMode]){
    int width = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.width;
    int height = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.height;

    NSSize size;

    size.width = width;
    size.height = height;

    [image setScalesWhenResized:YES];
    [image setSize:size];
}
```

Hope, this can help anyone.